# Getting the value of a Nullable Boolean using Reflection

Tags: c#, winforms, reflection

I'm trying to the value of a nullable boolean using reflection. The values are coming from a DB so I have to keep them the same.

Here is the code I am using.

```
public partial class PrinterConfigUC : UserControl
{
    prtsetup Printer { get; set; }

    public PrinterConfigUC(prtsetup printer)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Printer = printer;
        lblPrinterName.Text = Printer.prtname;

        var properties = printer.GetType().GetProperties();          

        foreach (var prop in properties)
        {
            //In debug, a nullable bool had a type name of "Nullable`1"
            if (prop.PropertyType.Name.Equals("Nullable`1"))
            {
                bool? tempBool = (bool?)prop.GetValue(prop, null);
            }
        }
    }
```

If I put a break point at `bool? tempBool = (bool?)prop.GetValue(prop, null);` and execute the line, the program stops further execution and just shows me a blank winform.  Nothing else happens. There are no error messages and the program doesn't crash, it just hangs on that one line.

Comment: Shouldn't that line be `bool? tempBool = (bool?)prop.GetValue(printer);`?

Comment: DavidG has it right. Will check the answer below as well once I can.  Thanks for the help.  Dumb mistake on my part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this:

```
bool? tempBool = (bool?)prop.GetValue(prop, null);
```

To:

```
bool? tempBool = (bool?)prop.GetValue(printer, null);
```

The first arg of GetValue is the source, which is the printer in your example above, not the property, which is metadata.